# Rust in VsCode, Hide Smart Comment

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

How To Hide Red Box Text Rust In VsCode?

[image]

Comment: This [tip](https://community.vscodetips.com/nickytonline/vs-code-tip-of-the-week-inlay-hints-configuration-options-3j9f) may help

Answer (score 0):

UnCheck Rust-ananlyzer Inlay Hints [image]